# Latin Numbering on the Navigation Pane

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I am facing the following problem.

Even though I have numbered the fist pages of my thesis with Latin numbering, the navigation pane on the left numbers them with Arabic numbering.

This creates a confusion when someone is trying to navigate from the contents numbering (e.g. Page 1 on the document is actually Page 9 on the Navigation Pane).

Ideally I would like to have Latin numbering on the Navigation Pane. I've seen that happening on other documents.
Any ideas how to achieve it?

[image: Miss-match between page and Navigation Pane numbering]

Answer (score 3):

Use hyperref:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter \lipsum
\mainmatter \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works fine. Is there a way to remove the page number from the cover (title) page?

Comment: There is no cover page in my example but normally it hasn't a page number (if you use \maketitle or the titlepage environment).